# Error 20080078:BIO routines:bio_write_intern: uninitialized

Tags: windows, php, ldap, openldap

My php test script for SSL connection to the LDAP server crashes.

When I run it from command line CLI crashes.

The message from the LDAP logging shows this before the crash:

> Error 20080078:BIO routines:bio_write_intern: uninitialized.

Not sure how to debug further.

Also, I've seen one or two similar issues online where they had bug with specific PHP versions and the LDAP version installed: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=37710

But in my case looks like I don't have the openldap commands to check it. Maybe because I'm using IIS?

What should I do to further debug it to find the cause?

Php version is 3.3.1. libcrypto version is 1.1.1.1.

How can I find out what it is? Maybe misconfiguration with IIS? But how to check? Ldap works when not using tlals

Comment: These normally indicate difference between ssl client and server compatible versions or/and fallback/upgrade of connection ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who will encounter this issue in the future: Looks like there is some bug with the specific PHP version I was using (7.3.1). After replacing the PHP files with a more recent PHP7 files I had (7.3.30), it started working - no change in code.

Not sure what is the issue - openLDAP or openSSL or PHP - but they did not mix together with this specific PHP version